# iOS design, quick solution for rotation

Tags: ios, user-interface, rotation

I think there is an dead easy solution for this and probably someone can give some simple advice. I have two elements in the view controller and want to change the the position depending on the rotation:

Portrait: Element A is on the bottom, Element B on the top

Landscape: Element A on the Left, Element B on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the UIViewController class willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: method to reposition Elements A and B. You can't do it using the autoresizing mask (in case you were considering that approach).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that and paste the code here once done.